# OpenLDAP Schema Modification difficulty

Tags: schema, openldap

I'm having a devil of a time adding SSH Keys to my schema on a fresh (debian package) openLDAP install. I am trying to use the following LDIF:

```
dn: cn=openssh-lpk,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: openssh-lpk
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.1.13 NAME 'sshPublicKey'
 DESC 'MANDATORY: Open SSH Public key'
 EQUALITY octetStringMatch
 SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40
 )
olcObjectClasses: (1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.2.0 NAME 'ldapPublicKey' SUP top AUXILIARY
 DESC 'MANDATORY: OpenSSH LPK objectclass'
 MAY ( sshPublicKey $ uid )
 )
```

with ldapadd and getting either Insufficient access (when i use the admin identity) or Unexpected token before ) (when running as root and using -Y EXTERNAL -H leap:///)

This is OpenLDAP version 2.5.13 (Debian Package) on Debian 12.